# How to recognize which mathematical function generated a curve given by X and Y arrays in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

How can I get the mathematical function from numerical values of X and Y array using sympy or however else in Python?

Just to be clear:
For following X and Y:

```
X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Y = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

I'd like to say that it is f(x) = kx+l, and with k and l if possible.

I have to find inverse of a function for which I only know a shape. It can be a fit, doesn't have to be 100% exact.

Comment: There's no general solution to this, because there may not be a simple mathematical function description.  You could use various curve fitting functions available in scipy, for instance, but it's up to you to decide what kinds of curves to fit and how to decide which is best.

Comment: What's going on in your example? The Y values are all the same so this is just a horizontal line, and I don't know what you mean by "f(y) = kx+l" since "kx+l" is clearly not a function of y.

Comment: Don't you mean `f(x)`? Is there a range of possible function types (i.e. polynomials, exponential, power, ...)?

Comment: @Jasper : Yeah, thanks. Started to write y = kx+l, changed my mind, and, obviously successfully messed things up. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to potentially be looking for the [`interpolate`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polyfuncs.interpolate) function from [`sympy.polys.polyfuncs`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/_modules/sympy/polys/polyfuncs.html), which can construct an interpolating polynomial for your data points. Note that this only does polynomial interpolation, it isn't some general equation-solver, which would be far more difficult.  Your given example is rather basic as your `f(x)` would just be `2` with `k = 0` and `l = 2`, but for a more general example you may have

```
from sympy.polys.polyfuncs import interpolate
from sympy.abc import x
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 5, 7]
data = list(zip(a,b))
print(interpolate(data,x))
```

**Outputs**:

```
2*x + 1
```

---

You can extract the coefficients from your polynomial with [`Poly.coeffs`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.coeffs) afterwards

```
result = sympy.polys.polyfuncs.interpolate(data,x)
coefficients = sympy.Poly(result).coeffs()
print(coefficients)
```

**Outputs**:

```
[2,1]
```

Comment: Just the thing I need! Apropo my example, why on Earth is it nonsensical just because k and l aren't something representative. It's done the trick. I wanted all to see from points that it is a line, because not all people name line coefficients k and l. So to shorten any possible confusions. Some people are bad with visualizing stuff. And so...

Comment: @Dalen Perhaps nonsensical was the wrong term, just "basic" :) and glad I could help.

Comment: Do you know how to get y from x? I successfully got a polynom that approximately gives me y for a given x value. But no matter what I do, I cannot get the x from a y. The X goes from 17 to zero, and Y is [19.683, 20.257, 20.802, 21.317, 21.801, 22.253, 22.673, 23.059, 23.412, 23.731, 24.015, 24.264, 24.478, 24.655, 24.796, 24.901, 24.969, 25.000]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you really need a fit routine, here some code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, k, l):
    return k * x + l

X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Y = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, X, Y)

print(popt)
print(pcov)
```

output for `k,l` would be

```
[ -2.18143147e-12   2.00000000e+00]
```

which makes sense, `Y` is constant

You could try any function shape just rewriting the `func` to your liking

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to determine the unique function that generated your series, since we can have multiple polynomial (or non-linear) solutions.

Imagine... there are many functions whose points are coincidents with the points in your series.

I think the most reasonably way to solve your problem is by using some regression techniques.

You can, for example, fit the data using the least squares method.

You should specify a model (ex. `y = a + bx + error`) and fit the data to this functional form.

Then you'll have coefficients like:

```
a = 0.2
b = 0.05

y = 0.2 + 0.05*x + error
```

Take a deep look at: [Regression Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis)